# Two WordPress in single docker and access by reverse proxy Nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, wordpress

Let's say I have a droplet with Nginx and setup reverse proxy to specific docker container subfolders. below is my reverse proxy setup for nginx

**Frontend Nginx**

```
#For Domain 1
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  domain1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000/domain1/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }
}

#For Domain 2
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  domain2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000/domain2/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }
}
```

**Backend Nginx**

I setup single docker and add two wordpress websites in sub folders. Like below

```
/var/www /root directory
/var/www/domain1 //domain 1 website 
/var/www/domain2 //domain 2 website
```

docker nginx conf.d file setup like below

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    #domain1 setup <----------- my issues might be here 
    location /domain1 {
            #try_files $uri $uri/  /domain1/index.php?$args;
        root /var/www/;
    }

    #domain2 setup <----------- my issues might be here 
    location /domain2 {
            #try_files $uri $uri/  /domain2/index.php?$args;
        root /var/www/;
    }

}
```

How could I setup in docker container for  nginx conf file to be able to  http://domain1.com and http://domain2.com

I found most answers are using separate docker container for each site. But I need using single container for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each site to answer to different hostnames then you need to use separate `server` blocks for each hostname in the backend, as you already did on the other nginx server.